# No Session handle to Renew Token in Xero-Partner-App

Tags: xero-api

**Error from Xero :**

> Token does not match an expected REQUEST token

The issue seems to be related to the comment from the Xero help site?

> This error will also occur if the session handle is not used in the
>   access token renewal process.

I have confirmed I do not get this on the return object of the following :

```
 public async Task<AccessTokenDto> Authorise(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier, string org)
 {
             var xeroacessToken = 
                       _authenticator.RetrieveAndStoreAccessToken(_user.Name, 
             oauth_token, oauth_verifier, org);
 }
```

I am not sure how I get the session handle and then how to use this in my service call to renew the token? As per the example I was expecting this on my token.

oauth_session_handle=ODJHMGEZNGVKMGM1NDA1NZG3ZWIWNJ 
"Session Handle used to renew the access token"

Code that works the first time with the token that has been retrieved from the database:

```
        var tokenStore = new MemoryTokenStore();
        tokenStore.Add(xerotoken);

        var api = new RA.Xero.Partner.Core(tokenStore, XeroUser(UserId)), _hostingEnvironment)
        {
            UserAgent = "My Partner App " + input.ConsumerKey,

        };
```

I tried to see if using the Partner Authentication directly would work :

```
        var tokenStore = new MemoryTokenStore();
        tokenStore.Add(xerotoken);
        Settings ApplicationSettings = new Settings();

        X509Certificate2 certificate = RA.Xero.Partner.Core.Certificate(_hostingEnvironment);

        var partnerAuthentication = new RA.Xero.Public.PartnerAuthenticator(
                ApplicationSettings.Uri,
                ApplicationSettings.AuthorizeUri,
                ApplicationSettings.CallBackUri,
                tokenStore,
                certificate
               );

        var consumer = new Consumer(ApplicationSettings.Key, 
         ApplicationSettings.Secret);
        var token = partnerAuthentication.GetToken(consumer, 
         XeroUser(UserId));
```

I have checked the keys are the partner keys in my app and any hints or sample code would be great.

Comment: Are you using one of the Xero-created SDKs? There are useful examples on Github in the two .NET repos - https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard and https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Net

Comment: Yes, the code from above is from the examples. Also we had the Public app working with the examples fine. It's only from switching over to use the Partner app that I cannot understand/seem to get the Session Handle.